# Assign input form to a variable

Tags: php

I have this input form which goes like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" />
```

I want to print it inside this variable:

```
$return .= '<div class="flink">'.$checkbox.'</div>';
```

or can i assign it to any other variable?

How can i do it? I tried putting :

```
$checkbox.= '<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" />';
```

Comment: What you have looks good.  What's your problem?

Comment: Whats the issue here. You are doing it correct. Just echo the variable to output

Comment: Why are you using `.=` on that last line?

Comment: what u r having ? any error or any output?

Comment: In the last line there is no need of a dot in front of = sign just $checkbox = '<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" />';

Comment: Hey Guys, i'm using . at the end because otherwise it wouldn't work! 
Well, i'm so sorry, it's just.. well, i was doing something else wrong. Everything's fine,, thanks ^^'

Comment: `.=` is used to append a string to an existing string.  `$x = "foo"; $x .= "bar"; echo $x;` will output `foobar`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to print a variable to the webpage, you can use several different commands.

- The [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) command is useful when the variable is HTML.
- The [`var_dump`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) command is useful for debugging purposes, as it works on all kinds of variables.
- [`print_r`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) is also nice, because it formats the output in a way that's readable.

Comment: `$return .= '<div class="flink">'.$checkbox.$link.'</div>';`  You can concatenate multiple strings in one command.  Then use one of the print functions I linked to.

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
$return = '<div class="flink">'.$checkbox.'</div>';
echo $return; // Somewhere on the page.
```

It looks like you're defining it fine, you just may not be echoing it out on the page.

Comment: Hey, one question, i've got $return .= '<div class="flink">'.$link.'</div>'; how can i add even the $checkbox, to appear?

Answer (score 0):

```
         <?php
                $q="select * from stores";
                $res=mysql_query($q);
                $StoreOPtion = '<option value="">--select--</option>';
                while($rs=mysql_fetch_object($res))
                 { 
                 $StoreOPtion .= '<option   value="'.$rs->StoreId.'||StoreName:'.$rs->StoreName.'..  Street:'.$rs->StoreStreet.'..Phone:'.$rs->StorePhone.'..Email:'.$rs->StoreEmail.'..Area:'.$rs->StoreArea.'..Pin:'.$rs->StorePincode.'">'.$rs->StoreName.'</option>';

                } 
                ?>
        <select name="StoreName" type="text" id="StoreName"  onchange="getStoreAdd()"/>
       <?php echo $StoreOPtion; ?>
         </select>
```

Here i am using dropdown box. ypu sehe this example and use it